# Fetching latest posts from 2 different WP installations

Tags: wp-load.php

I have three WordPress installations (cannot use multisite; cannot use RSS/Atom feeds) and I am trying to display a date-sorted list of the latest 10 posts from each of the two sub-sites on the main site home page.
The site is organized thus:
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/editorials
https://www.example.com/news

These are three separate installations of WordPress, however sharing the same database (with different db prefixes, of course).

I have tried creating a loop calling the wp-load.php function, but I cannot seem to get it to reset; instead, the second iteration simply re-displays the posts from the first loop (in this case, from ./editorials/wp-load.php).

I have tried to place all the posts in separate arrays, for later combining and sorting by date, i.e., $content1 and $content2, but I haven't gotten that far since I cannot fetch posts from the second instance.

Here is code:
https://pastebin.com/9REj1RhV

Thanks in advance!
-Brian

Comment: You could write a simple plugin that outputs the latest 10 posts in a serialized array when a special URL is called. Use that on the two sites. On the third you could then CURL said urls and parse the data into your feed. You could keep a cache of the curl too using WP transients.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response!  The base domain, https://www.example.com has no posts, only pages that do not need to be displayed.  The other two instances only have posts, no pages.  I think that cURL would be overkill, since all files are contained in the same filesystem (on the same server).  The posts are updated every 5 minutes, so I think caching would not be of benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the REST API to get the latest 10 posts from each install, then combine the two arrays, sort them by the date, and then only use the latest 10 results.

```
$editorials = wp_remote_get( 'https://www.example.com/editorials/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' );
$news       = wp_remote_get( 'https://www.example.com/news/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' );

$editorials = json_decode( $editorials[ 'body' ] );
$news       = json_decode( $news[ 'body' ] );

$all = array_merge( $editorials, $news );
//* The spaceship operator requires PHP > 7.0
usort( $all, function( $a, $b ) { return $a->date <=> $b->date; } );
$all = array_slice( $all, 0, 10 );

//* Do something useful with the combined array of posts
```

Comment: I tried the REST API but it failed; I'll try again and let you know.  Thanks!